# Battery information is wrong

Tags: 14.04, power-management, asus, battery

I have replaced the battery in my laptop with a lower capacity battery than what was previously inserted.

Ubuntu hasn't calibrated the battery metering system, and so the statistics & percentages are completely off.

How can I re-calibrate it?

**EDIT**

Already tried charging it overnight and discharging it completely to reset battery info.

Already tried holding power key for 10s while the battery and power is disconnected.

Comment: It could be the charging circuit itself. Not sure how one would check this without going to a PC repair shop and asking,

Comment: If I go to a PC repair store in India, There would be something wrong with my battery. Scratch That! There would be a lot wrong with my entire laptop.

Answer (score 1):

Often, the battery statistics come from a combination of the battery model info read by either the Bios or possibly the operating system and the measured duration of the battery. I don't believe the battery model info is read every time but the metering system will need a calibration run for it to properly guess at the duration time of the replacement battery. Simply run the fully charged replacement battery down using the Laptop in a consistent (normal) manner until it forces a shutdown. Then a full recharge. This should correct the battery metering. The same technique is used when replacing UPS batteries.

The calibration run is basically helping the battery management system that is always trying to measure the power duration of the battery do it's thing. Given that the battery is expected to change (weaken) over time, this circuit is always fine tuning it's duration estimate.

As for the charging circuit, is the Laptop's charging light on (after the battery has been drained somewhat)? Did the battery re-charge? If so, charging circuit is fine.

Comment: I have actually done that prior to asking the question. There was no change except that now everytime the Battery Charge Capacity chnages to match the charging I have done. If I charge to 72%, It changes automatically to 100% and the Battery Capacity match itself to Current Battery Charge.

Comment: I see. I'm not sure I understand what's happening (no change except it changes to match the charging). That's what we want isn't it? Please keep in mind that on any laptop & OS it's a guesstamation meter.  It will try to consistently predict a steady estimate as best as it can. Changes to that only factor in as a percentage so that there are no wild prediction swings due to an occasional heavy use. The Calibration is to try to make the biggest possible correction to that reading but it won't be 100% accurate after that. It will get better in time. Is the capacity prediction getting better?